# Unable to use default github actions env vars for composite step

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to utilize some of the [default github actions env vars](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#other-types-of-variables) within my [composite github action step](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action).  I recall reading (the link is long lost) somewhere that composite steps must be passed all of their parameters and don't have access to all the env vars, so I'm trying to do that.  However, I can't get the env var value to successfully get passed.

Notice here I'm using 3 different forms of syntax:

```
      - name: Do a thing
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
        with:
          repositoryUrl: ${{ env.GITHUB_SERVER_URL }}/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY
          commitSha: ${GITHUB_SHA}
          context: ${{ env.DOCKER_CONTEXT_PATH }}
          tags: ${{ needs.generate-tag.outputs.DOCKER_IMAGE }}
          dockerfile: ${{ env.DOCKERFILE_PATH }}
          push: true
          platforms: linux/amd64, linux/arm64
```

Those env vars get used by my action, and they're all read as a normal string except for  `GITHUB_SERVER_URL` which is empty.  I know this because I can see this snippet in the build output:

```
--label org.opencontainers.image.source="/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" --label org.opencontainers.image.revision="${GITHUB_SHA}"
```

Then within `.github/actions/my-action/action.yml` I have:

```
name: "Build image"
description: "Build and conditionally push an image to a remote ECR registry"
inputs:
  repositoryUrl:
    description: "The github repository URL"
    required: true
  commitSha:
    description: "The commit sha associated with this image"
    required: true
  tags:
    description: "If a new image is built, it will be assigned all of these tags"
    required: true
  context:
    description: "Docker context to use when building"
    required: true
  dockerfile:
    description: "Path to Dockerfile"
    required: true
  platforms:
    description: "Platforms to build"
    required: true
  push:
    description: "Whether to push the image after it's built"
    required: true
    default: 'false'
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - name: Build docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
      with:
        context: ${{ inputs.context }}
        tags: ${{ inputs.tags }}
        file: ${{ inputs.dockerfile }}
        platforms: ${{ inputs.platforms }}
        push: ${{ inputs.push }}
        labels: |
          org.opencontainers.image.source="${{ inputs.repositoryUrl }}"
          org.opencontainers.image.revision="${{ inputs.commitSha }}"
```

How can I ensure these values are passed dynamically without having to hard code them as strings?

Comment: I just did a quick test with a composite action and it did output all the expected env vars (with `run: env`). Why `${{ env.GITHUB_SERVER_URL }}` and not `$GITHUB_SERVER_URL`?

Comment: What env var did you test with?  Even using `${{ env.GITHUB_SERVER_URL }}` within the composite action it resolves as an empty string for me.

Comment: The `env` context is not populated by the default github env vars. Rather only things that are set in the workflow via `env` map or via `echo foo=bar >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in order to utilize github's native env vars within a composite step's `with:` section, you need to use `${{ github.server_url }}` instead of any form of `GITHUB_SERVER_URL` env var.  This means my action looks like:

```
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Generate labels
      id: labels
      shell: bash
      run: echo "CREATED=$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - name: Build docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
      with:
        context: ${{ inputs.context }}
        tags: ${{ inputs.tags }}
        file: ${{ inputs.dockerfile }}
        platforms: ${{ inputs.platforms }}
        push: ${{ inputs.push }}
        labels: |
          org.opencontainers.image.source="${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}"
          org.opencontainers.image.revision="${{ github.sha }}"
          org.opencontainers.image.created="${{ steps.labels.outputs.CREATED }}"
```

ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context